# How to make a function skip an argument from a vector

Tags: r

Say I have the following function

```
power<-function (number){
   number^2
  }
```

I also have a vector -z

z<- c(1:3, "a", 7:9)

I would like to apply the power function over the vector variables. If everything is a number, the  functions works well using this code, which creates a list as I want:

```
q<-lapply(z, FUN=power)
```

How do I make the function skip, if it does not find a valid argument? In this case skip "a". Let's say removing the odd argument is not an option for my task. I might also have cases when the function does not find the argument at all (e.g. empty space, missing tag on a web page). Would be nice if the solution could work for these instances as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a `list` instead of a `vector` as `list` can have multiple types whereas `vector` can have only a single class and if there is a single `character` element, it returns the whole object as `character`

```
z <- list(1:3, "a", 7:9)
lapply(Filter(is.numeric, z), FUN = power)
```

---

Or with `map_if`

```
library(purrr)
map_if(z, .p = is.numeric, .f = power)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 9

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] 49 64 81
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun. I'll accept it, but do you know if there is a way to skip a non-valid argument without filtering? Let's say I have several documents and I would like the function to select in a list documents with certain words in their title. If those words are not there then I'd like it to skip the document and check the next one.

Comment: @Vasile Try the `map_if` which does that or use `i1 <- sapply(z, is.numeric); z[i1] <- lapply(z[i1],  power)`

Answer (score 4):

This will try to coerce the elements of the supplied vector to numeric. Values not coercible will have NA returned. Note that your input vector z may not be what you intended, i.e. it resolves to a character vector c("1", "2", "3", "a", ...) and *not* c(1, 2, 3, "a", 7, 8, 9).

```
power<-function (number){
  result<- as.numeric(number)^2
  }

z <- c(1:3, "a", 7:9)

lapply(z, power)


 [[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 9

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] 49

[[6]]
[1] 64

[[7]]
[1] 81
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also write a custom function that wraps `power` inside `lapply`. Basically an equivalent of `map_if`:

```
z <- list(1:3, "a", 7:9)

lapply(z, function(x) {
  if(all(is.numeric(x))) {
    power(x)
  } else {
    x
  }
})

[[1]]
[1] 1 4 9

[[2]]
[1] "a"

[[3]]
[1] 49 64 81
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
power <- Vectorize(function(number) {
    ifelse(is.numeric(number), number^2, number)
})
z <- list(1:3, "a", 7:9)
lapply(z, power)
```

which gives

```
> lapply(z, power)
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 9

[[2]]
  a
"a"

[[3]]
[1] 49 64 81
```